# Rails: Ordering parents by grand children's attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord

```
class User
  has_many :calendars
  has_many :cars, through: :calendars
end

class Calendar
  has_many :cars
end

class Car
  # attribute `issued_at`
end
```

I need to order users by `issued_at` of his cars. So ordering the parent by the grand children's attribute `issued_at`.

Here is so far:

```
@q = User.active.joins(:cars).order('cars.issued_at').group('users.id')
```

But I'm getting

```
column "cars.issued_at" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
```

Comment: since a user may have many cars, which value of `issued_at` should be used for the ordering? This question is the implication of the error message you get: you did not tell PostgreSQL which value of all the possible `issued_at` it should use to order. You could use `max(cars.issued_at)` to order by _latest_, for example, but this depends on your needs.

Comment: What @MrYoshiji said. However if you are interested in all the `User`s being ordered by all the `issue_at` dates then just remove the `group` portion. User objects may be displayed more than once as they appear in this ordering

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `distinct` instead of `group` to get rid of the duplicates:

```
@q = User.active.joins(:cars).order('cars.issued_at').distinct
```

Answer (score 1):

here is a reproduction repo: https://github.com/localhostdotdev/bug/tree/ordering-parents-by-grand-children

when making the same query I don't see any error, the issue must be in your `active` scope.

here is the full query with a `scope :active, -> { where(active: true) }`:

```sql
SELECT "users".*
FROM "users"
INNER JOIN "calendars" ON "calendars"."user_id" = "users"."id"
INNER JOIN "cars" ON "cars"."calendar_id" = "calendars"."id"
WHERE "users"."active" = ?
GROUP BY users.id
ORDER BY cars.issued_at
LIMIT ?
```

I'm unable to reproduce your issue.

Comment: Yes right I'm also not able to reproduce it as I removed 'active' scope. It's working fine. `User.joins(:cars).order('cars.issued_at').group('users.id')`